# Clean output using sed

Tags: bash, sed, cat

I have a file that begins with this kind of format

```
INFO|NOT-CLONED|/folder/another-folder/another-folder|last-folder-name|
```

What I need is to read the file and get this output:

```
INFO|NOT-CLONED|last-folder-name
```

I have this so far:

```
cat clone_them.log | grep 'INFO|NOT-CLONED' | sed -E 's/INFO\|NOT-CLONED\|(.*)/g'
```

But is not working as intended

**NOTE:** the last "another-folder" and "last-folder-name is the same

Comment: In general, there's no need to do `grep pattern | sed ...`.  You can use `sed` to do the filtering.  In this case: `sed -n '/INFO|NOT-CLONED/s/...//p` . Note that I've replaced your substitution with `...` because `sed` is the wrong tool for this.  I'm just pointing out that `grep | sed` is an anti-pattern.

Comment: it's possible to use `cut` for this as well, `cat clone_them.log | cut -d'|' -f3`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non greedy (reluctant) regex matching in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-reluctant-regex-matching-in-sed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a sed solution:

```
$ sed -En 's/(INFO\|NOT-CLONED\|).*\|([^|]*)\|$/\1\2/p' file
INFO|NOT-CLONED|last-folder-name
```

How it works:

- `-E`

  Use extended regex
- `-n`

  Don't print unless we explicitly tell it to.
- `s/(INFO\|NOT-CLONED\|).*\|([^|]*)\|$/\1\2/p`

  Look for lines that include `INFO|NOT-CLONED|` (save this in group 1) followed by anything, `.*`, followed by `|` followed by any characters not `|`, `[^|]*` (saved in group 2), followed by `|` at the end of the line.  The replacement text is group 1 followed by group 2.

  The `p` option tells sed to print the line if the match succeeds.  Since the substitution only succeeds for lines that contain `INFO|NOT-CLONED|`, this eliminates the need for an extra `grep` process.

#### Variation: Returning just the last-folder-name

To just get the `last-folder-name` without the `INFO|NOT-CLONED`, we need only  remove `\1` from the output:

```
$ sed -En 's/(INFO\|NOT-CLONED\|).*\|([^|]*)\|$/\2/p' file
last-folder-name
```

Since we no longer need the first capture group, we could simplify and remove the now unneeded parens so that the only capture group is the last folder name:

```
$ sed -En 's/INFO\|NOT-CLONED\|.*\|([^|]*)\|$/\1/p' file
last-folder-name
```

Comment: Thank you this is the answer I was looking for, I just have a doubt, if I need to just get the last-folder-name without the INFO|NOT-CLONED I just need to delete that part?

Comment: @MateoGutierrez I'm glad this worked for you.  I just updated the answer with code to get just the `last-folder-name` without the `INFO|NOT-CLONED`.

Answer (score 1):

Its simpler in `awk` as input file is properly delimited by `|` symbol. You need to tell `awk` that the input fields are separated by `|` and output should also remain separated with `|` symbol using `IFS` and `OFS` respectively.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}/INFO\|NOT-CLONED/{print $1,$2,$(NF-1)}' clone_them.log
INFO|NOT-CLONED|last-folder-name
```