# How do I get sed to substitute the first occurance of a complex string ending in a multi character delimiter?

Tags: regex, sed, delimiter

I have a long line of text and html tags.  I wish to use sed to replace the characters between the string with the value '**MYSTART**' up to the first occurance of `</p>` after the starting string.  The substituting text is **RESULTSAFTERSUBSTITUTIONWORKS**

I've been fumbling and bumbling with regular expressions and keep hitting a brick wall.  I also tried a few regex test sites but what they report as success doesn't work in sed for me either with or without using the '-r'.

`cat myfile | sed -r 's/MYSTART.*?<\/p>/RESULTAFTERSUBSTITUTIONWORKS/'`

My sample string looks something like this:

`THISSHOULDBEIGNORED_MYSTART<ac>blah</ac><another>lots of things 123 abc :</another></p><div><ac>another thing</another><p>welcome home to somewhere</p></div>the line keeps going and going</p><p>paragraph</p>`

After substitution it would look like this:

`THISSHOULDBEIGNORED_RESULTAFTERSUBSTITUTIONWORKS<div><ac>another thing</another><p>welcome home to somewhere</p></div>the line keeps going and going</p><p>paragraph</p>`

Comment: In case perl is an option:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-reluctant-regex-matching-in-sed/1103177#1103177

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With any sed that recognizes `\n` as meaning `<newline>`:

```
$ sed 's:</p>:\n:; s/MYSTART.*\n/RESULTAFTERSUBSTITUTIONWORKS/' file
THISSHOULDBEIGNORED_RESULTAFTERSUBSTITUTIONWORKS<div><ac>another thing</another><p>welcome home to somewhere</p></div>the line keeps going and going</p><p>paragraph</p>
```

If you can have `</p>`s before your start string then it'd be more like this (untested):

```
sed 's:</p>:\n:g; s/MYSTART[^\n]*\n/RESULTAFTERSUBSTITUTIONWORKS/; s:\n:</p>:g'
```