# sed find and replace from left most character

Tags: sed

sed appears to find and replace from right to left.

for example:

`echo "a_b_c_d" | sed 's/.*\(_.*\)/\1/'`

outputs

`_d`

but why doesn't

`echo "a_b_c_d" | sed 's/^.*\(_.*\)/\1/'`

or

`echo "a_b_c_d" | sed 's/.*\(_.*$\)/\1/'`

output

`_b_c_d`

since these do not output `_b_c_d` how should this be done?

How should sed be used to find on first character and not last character when performing a find and replace?

Comment: `.*` is greedy, so it makes the farthest match possible

Comment: `.*` is a greedy one, rather try something like: `echo "a_b_c_d" | sed 's/[^_]*\(_.*\)/\1/'` to get `_b_c_d`. Which has everything before first `_` before matched and rest of first `_` saved into back reference to be used later.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Non greedy (reluctant) regex matching in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-reluctant-regex-matching-in-sed)

Answer (score 1):

`.*` is greedy pattern that matches longest possible substring before matching following pattern, `_` in this case. So placing `.*` before `_` makes it match longest possible match before matching last `_` in your input.

> since these do not output _b_c_d how should this be done?

```
echo "a_b_c_d" | sed 's/^[^_]*\(_.*$\)/\1/'

_b_c_d
```

Here `[^_]*` is negated *bracket expression* (called character class in modern regex flavors) that matches 0 or more of any character that is not `_`.