# Capture group in specific string

Tags: sed

I have a string:

```
User{self=https:example.com, name=S1234, displayName=Johny B, accountId=null, emailAddress=johny.b@example.com, active=true}'
```

I try to capture group and get `Johny B` in sed.
I have proper regex: `displayName=(.*?),`

but below sed command return me all string:

```
's/.*displayName=\(.*?\),/\1/'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Non greedy (reluctant) regex matching in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-reluctant-regex-matching-in-sed)

Comment: ok, when I change to ```'s/.*displayName=\([^/]*\),/\1/'``` I get substring starting of```Johny B``` to the end of string

Comment: You have a comma to exclude, `'s/.*displayName=\([^,]*\),/\1/'`, not a slash.

Comment: It returns incorrect substring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `sed`

```
sed -E 's/.*displayName=([^,]*).*/\1/' $file
```

You have further strings after the match which you need to account for.