# How to use SED to extract string

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I am very new to sed.

I wanted to extract the id from

```json
{ "requestId": "aee4f0cd-4b15-4df5-ab6b-62874963105a" }
```

and return `aee4f0cd-4b15-4df5-ab6b-62874963105a`.

How do I do it using sed ?

Comment: That looks like JSON. Have you considered using `jq`?

Comment: That looks like JSON. A parser like [tag:jq] would be a better fit. `echo '{ "requestId": "aee4f0cd-4b15-4df5-ab6b-62874963105a" }' | jq -r '.requestId'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Non greedy (reluctant) regex matching in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-reluctant-regex-matching-in-sed)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing JSON with Unix tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `jq` is a better solution, but by `sed` you should apply this:

```sh
echo '{ "requestId": "aee4f0cd-4b15-4df5-ab6b-62874963105a" }' | sed -r 's/^.*: "(.+)".*$/\1/'
```

Answer (score 2):

jq is better:

```
s='{ "requestId": "aee4f0cd-4b15-4df5-ab6b-62874963105a" } '

echo "$s" | jq '.requestId'
"aee4f0cd-4b15-4df5-ab6b-62874963105a"
```

Or, no quotes:

```
echo "$s" | jq -r '.requestId'
aee4f0cd-4b15-4df5-ab6b-62874963105a
```