# How to extract the password from this string in bash: "--db_host db --db_password $£é5+dd/gcç# --db_name zorgl"?

Tags: regex, sed, regex-group

I have tried this on Debian, but it fails:

```
echo "--db_host db --db_password $£é5+dd/gcç# --db_name zorgl" | sed -e "s/^.*db_password *\([^ ]+\) +.*$/\1/"
```

Result (no match):

```
--db_host db --db_password $£é5+dd/gcç# --db_name zorgl
```

Expected result:

```
$£é5+dd/gcç#
```

Comment: Which OS are you on? What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/.*db_password ([^ ]*).*/\1/' input_file
$£é5+dd/gcç#
```

Comment: It fails for me with "invalid byte sequence" which switching to `-E` does nothing to fix.

Comment: @tripleee Are you on Mac? Using GNU sed should work

Comment: This was on a Mac, yes. The OP doesn't reveal how their `sed` is failing so the fact remains that `-E` is unlikely to fix their problem.

Comment: Hmm. I see your point @tripleee. Guess we would need to wait for some form of elaboration from OP

Comment: @HatLess' solution works for me. From the man page: "-E, -r, --regexp-extended, use extended regular expressions in the script (for portability use POSIX -E)."

Answer (score 0):

Post by HatLess will fail if password contains space.  This should do:

```
sed -E 's/.*db_password (.*?) --db_name.*/\1/' file
$£é5+d d/gcç#
```

Comment: I think sed does not recognize the non greedy quantifier https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-reluctant-regex-matching-in-sed